# What is the attribute returned when AsyncMock called (not awaited)?

Tags: python, asynchronous, mocking, python-asyncio

## General

I am writing a unit test for async code in python 3.10 and I would like to have make sure that proper coroutines/futures are passed to certain functions/async functions.

## My code Example

Let's assume that I have such product file (there might be some defects as I am about to test it):

**product.py**

```
from asyncio import wait_for

async def main_async_function():
    await wait_for(fut=some_async_func(), timeout=1)

async def some_async_func():
    ...  # content is irrelevant
```

Normally, I would patch functions and have such test file:

**test.py**

```
import pytest
from mock import patch

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("product.some_async_func")
@patch("product.wait_for")
async def test_main_async_function(mock_wait_for, mock_some_async_func):
    await main_async_function()
    mock_wait_for.assert_called_once_with(fut=mock_some_async_func.return_value, timeout=1)
    mock_some_async_func.assert_called_once_with()
```

## The root cause - AsyncMock

Unfortunately it does not work as I have discovered a strange behavior of `AsyncMock` as `return_value` attribute represents the value returned when awaited and I cannot find the attribute returned when called.

```
from mock import AsyncMock

some_async_mock = AsyncMock()
assert some_async_mock.return_value == some_async_mock()  # this raises an exception is the mock was called, not awaited
```

Comment: I've added an answer for the thing you are asking, but your actual example is still unclear to me. Nothing in your code actually runs ``some_async_func`` – both it or ``wait_for`` require an active event loop that ``await``s them, and that's nowhere to be seen in your code.

Comment: My mistake, we can assume both functions are async (I have changed the code a little bit and forgot to update the example. Thank you for pointing this out).

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncMock` represents an *async* callable. Same as for an `async def` function, to get its return value one has to call *and `await`* it. The call provides an *awaitable* for the return value, and `await`ing the awaitable provides the return value itself.

```py
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock

some_async_mock = AsyncMock()
#                                      v async ............ v callable
assert some_async_mock.return_value == await some_async_mock()
```

Note that the `await` is only possible in an async context, such as a coroutine run by `asyncio`, an ipython REPL, or another event loop.

Comment: The point is that `asyncio.wait_for` function requires a future that is not awaited yet. Is there any way to get this value from the mock, so I could make sure that I pass the proper future to the function?

Comment: @Maciek ``asyncio.wait_for`` requires an *awaitable*, not specifically a ``Future``. ``some_async_mock()`` is an awaitable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems (as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock)) that `AsyncMock` always returns coroutine when called, which then returns value specified as `return_value`. However, there is a way to setup the unit test the way you need. `mock.patch` has keyword argument `new_callable` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)) which allows you to override the `AsyncMock` for coroutines with `Mock` or `MagicMock`.

Your test example can be made to work like this:

**product.py**

```py
from asyncio import wait_for
    
async def main_async_function():
     await wait_for(fut=some_async_func(), timeout=1)
    
async def some_async_func():
   ...  # content is irrelevant
```

**test.py**

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from product import main_async_function

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("product.some_async_func", new_callable=MagicMock())
@patch("product.wait_for")
async def test_main_async_function(mock_wait_for, mock_some_async_func):
    await main_async_function()
    mock_wait_for.assert_called_once_with(
              fut=mock_some_async_func.return_value,
              timeout=1)
    mock_some_async_func.assert_called_once_with()
```

Note though that this makes `mock_some_async_func` no longer awaitable.